# How to disable wireless N on Centos/RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel, wifi

On a RHEL7 notebook we have a:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

card, which we want to use only with "G" mode, "N" should be disabled. How can we do this? iwconfig command doesn't exists by default.

**Question**: How can we check that my wireless is using G or N currently? Under RHEL 7, no iwconfig. And how can we set it to use only G by default?

It is needed to set it to G because "N" mode has bugs.

Comment: You're attacking the issue from the wrong side here.  Set your Wireless Router to Broadcast only G...

Comment: updated the question

Comment: As I said set the router to broadcast in only G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Wireless N in the module

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl-opt.conf
```

Reboot

But I would suggest enabling Wireless N on the router and trying this option

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl-opt.conf
```

This command enables aggressive TX on Wireless-N and fixes a lot of issues

Comment: didn't helped an original problem, but this was the answer to the q, thanks!